# How to time browser when opening new tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabs, selenium-chromedriver, wait

I have the following code for when I need to click on an item, which opens in a new tab,and I need to switch the browser to that tab.

```
def ThingsinTab(browser):

   clickbutton=Somefunction #Find where to click

   clickbutton.click()

   try:  

      WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
      EC.number_of_windows_to_be(len(old_tabs)+1))
   except: return browser

   THIS POINT!!

   new_window=(set(browser.window_handles)-old_tabs).pop()
   browser.switch_to.window(new_window)

   #Do some stuff with this tab

   browser.close()  
   browser.switch_to_window(main_tab)

   return browser
```

Sometimes the tab opens, but it remains with a grey background, not fully loaded for a long while. I have narrowed where the code is stuck in this point and I signaled it in the code above. 
What I want is a way to time the new variable `new_window` and the switch, so that if let's say, after 10 seconds it hasn't move on in the code, it stops, closes the new tab and return the browser.

Provided this function is a part of a bigger code, I would like to know as well how to time in the bigger script this function, so if it takes more than a number of seconds, it interrupts the function from running and resume the rest of the code.

```
Big script

some things

ThingsinTab() #I want to set a maximum time for this function to complete its code,or else stop it and move on.

More some things
```

Answer (score 0):

You could spin off a thread that opens the window, then wait for a maximum of 10 seconds. If it hasn't finished by then, kill the thread and perform your alternative strategy.

You might find the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module useful. [`thread.join(10)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) can do the "wait for a maximum of 10 seconds" part; it shouldn't be *too* hard to put this together, aside from the usual difficulty of getting threads to work.